# .NET Maui with .NET Core 7.0 - Install wasm-tools

Tags: maui

I'm getting the following error on a .NET Maui project:

```
Error   NETSDK1147  To build this project, the following workloads must be installed:
wasm-tools

To install these workloads, run the following command: dotnet workload restore MyProjectName
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.401\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.
ImportWorkloads.targets
```

I've tried the following steps and between each, I closed `Visual Studio 2022` and re-opened it every time but to no avail. Some of the messages outputted after running the various command have been included.

1. Deleted the bin & obj folders for the .net mauid mobile app project
2. Ran `dotnet clean`
3. Ran `dotnet restore`

   Determining projects to restore...

   Restored project1

   Restored project2
   ....

   Restored project x
4. Ran `dotnet workload restore`:

   Installing workloads

   .... installing various other pack/libraries

   Successfully installed workload(s) android maui wasm-tools wasm-tools-net7.
5. Ran `dotnet workload install wasm-tools`

   Workload(s) 'wasm-tools' are already installed.

   .... installing various other pack/libraries

   Successfully installed workload(s) wasm-tools android maui wasm-tools-net7.

Any ideas what's causing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It just started happening for while building a Maui project. There was no obvious cause. I am trying running `dotnet workload install wasm-tools-net7`
then `dotnet workload restore`,  both from my solution directory. It seems to have fixed it.
You can probably just run `dotnet workload restore`